# contouring does not detect an object inside another object

Tags: opencv, contour

I am trying to detect the number of contours on this image. Ideally supposed to be 3 but due to noise I was not getting idle result. Hence i tried to blur the image before thresholding it as below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img= cv2.imread('Inkedblueimagewithdot.jpg')
cv2.imshow('original',img)
blur= cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(img,21,49)
gray_image= cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh= cv2.threshold(gray_image,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, contours,hierarchy =cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print(len(contours))
contourimage=cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(255,255,255),20)
cv2.imshow('countors',contourimage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output is:

```
2
```

This is the input image:
[This is the input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWifK.jpg%5C)

This is the output image:[This is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixKvD.png)

Comment: For getting the internal nested contours as well, you need to use `cv2.RETR_TREE` instead of `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`, You can also look for other [methods](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71) available in OpenCV

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me if we can only crop the center rectangle along with the dot?

Comment: Yes sure, you may use: `x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)`, This [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) contains some other helpful operations on contours

Comment: ya i did try but does not work for me

Comment: cnt at this statement changes for every image as I have images some with pixels outside this rectangle and also some noises

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain 3 contours , you could use `cv2.RETR_LIST`. It lists all the contours present in the binary image irrespective of any hierarchy as mentioned [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html)

To answer the second question, you could try setting an area constraint such that contours below a certain area would be discarded. For the image provided I set an area of 4000:

```
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 4000:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        roi = image[y  :y + h, x : x + w ]

        cv2.imshow('cropped_region', roi)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I tried doing this, but the problem is that blue part of the image is some times tilted and i would lose the edges. I have lot of images which are little tilted due to capturing alignment issues.

Comment: the black dot here represents a defective pixel (only for usecase it is big in size) which is generally small in size and would not be considered if i apply this area condition. I would like to get the blue part of the image along with all the pixels in it(good or bad)

Comment: The defective pixel is present since it is enclosed within the blue box. It certainly does not satisfy the area criterion.

Comment: when i applied this area condition after contouring the output image does not have this dot anymore if the black dot size is anything less than the area condition mentioned

Comment: @MeenakshiChowdhary Since the boxes are sometimes titled you could use the [minimum rectangular area](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9) which does not crop the edges.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I shall try that and post again.. Have a nice day :)

Comment: :when do rect on contour we want get x,z,w,h and when we crop it the output image should only contain that contour ryt.. why r we getting this black area as well